# Why did I get multiple awards for each tag edit?

Tags: bug, reputation

I edited two tags: [satellite](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/satellite) and [katello](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/katello) but it seems that I got `+2` reputation twice for each edit:

[image: Awards]

Any ideas why?

Comment: `satellite` doesn't seem to be in the system any more.  The `katello`  tag wiki excerpt lacks usage guidance and starts with "Katello is a layered systems management application for Unix systems, primarily GNU/Linux. It is a layered product ..". A layered application that is a layered product, really? IMO you were lucky to get this approved.

Comment: Slight levels of redundancy are truly a sign of the end times. fwiw I submitted a revision that took the first "layered product" mention out. Each had a purpose but I agree that it sounds repetitious being so close together.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can edit a tag wiki and a tag excerpt separately (through the system doesn't allow you to create a tag wiki, if the tag excerpt isn't created), so you get reputation for each one equally.

Comment: Alright, I think that was it. I just didn't realize they were itemized separately reputation-wise.

Comment: Also, why did you change the satellite tag to "redhat-satellite"? Is there another product called "satellite" out there?

Comment: @Bratchley Many! Toshiba's laptop for starters.

Comment: Alright I guess. Not really U&L related but I see your point.